# How can I display a magento block in more than one location?

Tags: magento, block

I'm trying to display the cross sell block in it's normal location as well as at the bottom of the page. There is more than one phtml template file involved so $this->getChildHtml does not work in the second location since the block is setup to only be on the cart.phtml file as of now.

In summary, how can I display the same block in more than one template file? I wan't to place these changes in my local.xml and do not want to modify core Magento template files.

Answer (score 0):

The core layout directive for this block is set up as a child of the **checkout.cart** block:

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    <!-- ... -->
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
            <!-- ... -->
            <block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
 </checkout_cart_index>
```

To add it to the footer, you *might* need to only establish another parent-child relationship in your *local.xml*:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="footer">
        <action method="insert"><!-- or "append" to add to the end -->
            <child>checkout.cart.crosssell</child>
        </action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

This approach relies on the stock *page/html/footer.phtml* template which contains an empty `getChildHtml()` call, which causes it to render all child blocks.

**Note that the footer block class `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer` has a never-expiring `block_html` cache lifetime, *and* it does not evaluate child contents for its cache entry.** You may need to disable the cache for this block or rewrite the block class to account for the varied content of the crosssell block.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks! To avoid the caching issue, how would I setup a custom block? I understand I'd have to change the reference name to the new block name, but how do I set the block itself up?